# How to change css style through query with NO class NO id

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to change the font size of p however, there is no p element (with a class or id) in my html. If it was, I would just use

```
$('#final').append("<p>You won! Congrats!</p>");


$(.someClassInMyHtml).css({'font-size': '40px'});
```

However, since I just create the p element -how can I do that?

```
$(.someClassInMyHtml).css ...
```

Thanks!!

Comment: $('#final').append("<p style='font-size:40px;'>You won! Congrats!</p>");

Answer (score 3):

You can save your new element into a variable to modify it later:

```
var pElement=$("<p>You won! Congrats!</p>");
$('#final').append(pElement);
pElement.css({'font-size': '40px'});
```

Or, if you want to change *all* p-elements, use this:

```
$("p").css({'font-size': '40px'});
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `.apendTo()` you'll get the Element you want, then you can use `.css()`:

```
$('<p>You won! Congrats!</p>').appendTo('#final').css({fontSize: '40px'});
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you know why this isn't working:  html:                         <button class="button1" id="play">play</button> and jquery :  $('.button1').on('click', function(){
       $(this).effect('bounce',{times:3},500); 
        });